# How to deal with Mongodb Null values

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have some sample data here. What the code is supposed to do is to remove any words inside. However, occasionally mongo throws in a Null value or an empty string.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1],[4],[25],['asd123'],['asdf1']]),
                   columns=['account'])


df["account"] = (
            df["account"]
            .fillna((-1), inplace=False)).astype("str").str.replace(r"[^0-9]", "", regex=True).astype('int64')
```

I have tried replacing it with an integer below, but Python keeps throwing me an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1],[4],[25],['asd123'],['']]),
                   columns=['account'])
np.where(df.applymap(lambda x: x == ''))
df.replace('', '1')


df["account"] = (
            df["account"]
            .fillna((-1), inplace=False)).astype("str").str.replace(r"[^0-9]", "", regex=True).astype('int64')
df
```

I have also tried and it doesnt work too:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1],[4],[25],['asd123'],['']]),
                   columns=['agent_account'])
np.where(df.applymap(lambda x: x == ''))
df.replace('','abc1',regex = True)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to convert "" to an integer. Just delete the "" when getting the data, with this line `df.drop(df[df.account == ""].index, inplace=True)`

This would be your modified code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1],[4],[25],['asd123'],['']]),
                   columns=['account'])
np.where(df.applymap(lambda x: x == ''))
df.drop(df[df.account == ""].index, inplace=True)


df["account"] = (
            df["account"]
            .fillna((-1), inplace=False)).astype("str").str.replace(r"[^0-9]", "", regex=True).astype('int64')
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your problem, please mark it as best answer. If you need any further help, please comment on this post. Thanks!

Comment: ohhh got it. thanks a lot for your help! really appreciate it. have a gd one

Comment: You can just use the `df.replace()` function like this `df.replace("", 1, inplace=True)` for example if you want to replace with a 1. Just change the int you want